# Xcode 6.0 Swift, errors appeared: can't evoke'!=' with an argument list

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6

Once the Swift language was finalized and I updated my Xcode to the latest version, my program written in Swift reported a bunch of errors. The one I still couldn't solve is "can't evoke'!=' with an argument list of type '(NSPersistentStoreCoordinator, NiLiteralConvertible)'

The code is in the app delegate class and I was trying to implement core data here.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?


func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    self.saveContext()
}
func saveContext () {
    var error: NSError? = nil
    let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext
    if (_managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if managedObjectContext.hasChanges && !managedObjectContext.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            //println("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

// #pragma mark - Core Data stack

// Returns the managed object context for the application.
// If the context doesn't already exist, it is created and bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.
var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext {

if !(_managedObjectContext != nil) {

    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator

    if coordinator != nil {   

//This is where the error was reported. 

    _managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    _managedObjectContext!.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    }

    }
    return _managedObjectContext!
}
var _managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = nil

// Returns the managed object model for the application.
// If the model doesn't already exist, it is created from the application's model.
var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel {
if !(_managedObjectModel != nil) {
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("InTheDark", withExtension: "momd")
    _managedObjectModel = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)
    }
    return _managedObjectModel!
}
var _managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel? = nil

// Returns the persistent store coordinator for the application.
// If the coordinator doesn't already exist, it is created and the application's store added to it.
var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator {
if !(_persistentStoreCoordinator != nil) {
    let storeURL = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("InTheDark.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    _persistentStoreCoordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    if _persistentStoreCoordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: storeURL, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {


        abort()
    }
    }
    return _persistentStoreCoordinator!
}
var _persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = nil

// #pragma mark - Application's Documents directory

// Returns the URL to the application's Documents directory.
var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL {
let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.endIndex-1] as NSURL
}


}
```

Can someone help me out please?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `persistentStoreCoordinator` is declared to be an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`, not an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator?` or an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator!`, it cannot be `nil`.  Therefore you aren't allowed to compare it to nil.  You can get rid of the `nil` check, or change `persistentStoreCoordinator`'s type to end in `?` or `!`.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this just mostly the stub code from the default Application project with CoreData? Just create a new project and check off include CoreData. Xcode should generate a proper version of this template for you that you can copy/paste.

Template code in the newest Xcode 6 release:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.tea.Test2" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1] as NSURL
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Test2", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("Test2.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    if coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil, error: &error) == nil {
        coordinator = nil
        // Report any error we got.
        let dict = NSMutableDictionary()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason
        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error
        error = NSError.errorWithDomain("YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
        abort()
    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext()
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if let moc = self.managedObjectContext {
        var error: NSError? = nil
        if moc.hasChanges && !moc.save(&error) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Oh    Yes! What was I thinking about!  Thank you!  I'll try and see what happens.

Comment: It turns out that the latest Xcode doesn't provide a "Use Core Data" check potion as it did before. Well, I tried several times with different projects. But I still couldn't find the option.

Comment: It does. Just like every version of Xcode, the template option appears when selecting iOS/Application/Single View Application. Ensure the language is set to Swift and check off Use Core Data.

Comment: I've also added the template code above for you to reference.